# Github pull request - compare all commits of master branch

Tags: github

I found many ways to [compare](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/) two commits/branches/tags, but I can't find a way to compare all commits in branch.

Suppose we have only branch master with 4 commits
[example](https://github.com/kosciej16/xlstokp)

We can easily compare all commits except first one in [that](https://github.com/kosciej16/xlstokp/compare/master%5E%5E%5E...master) or
[that](https://github.com/kosciej16/xlstokp/compare/b0182e6f1a2ea52c2f0bb08ff8585c3a4d686d10...master) way

But none of these include changes from 'empty repository' state.
How could I do that?

Comment: A commit represents a state of the repository, but it is often associated with the changes leading to that state. Comparing two states with each other is something I can understand, but what does it mean to you to compare one or ten states? Then, empty repository is also a state, the difference between that and a commit is just the content of the repo at that commit/state. In summary, at least one of us doesn't understand what's going on.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yeah, I explained it wrong. I mean to compare state before first commit with state after last commit.